# Form styling ruby css

Tags: css

I'm trying to style my login form and i have the code in the style sheets for login problem is it changes the style of another form i have on another page to match the one from the login is there some way to stop this from happening

```
.form {
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto 10px;
padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
font-size: 16px;
width: 300px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=password] {
color: #000000;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
border-radius: 0px; 
height: 60px;
margin: 6px auto;
text-indent: 10px; 
}

.btn-submit {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: #008CBA;
padding: 10px 20px;
border: 0;
margin-top: 6px; 
}
```

Comment: Please post some code by which we can see the issue. Without code we can't help.

Comment: Are you tried to make the login form in HTML + CSS and the login backend with RoR?

Comment: no i haven't tried that il try it to see if it works

Comment: Add a class  to your form (like `login_form`) and only change the css definition for forms with that class. I will remove the rails and ruby tags from your question, because this is a pure html and css topic.

Comment: If you can post your HTML it will be fantastic. And, try using the `input` tag only for CSS selectors instead of `input` + types.